# shell : convert string to array

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am trying to convert string variable to an array with following code.

```
#/bin/sh
VERSION='1.2.3'
echo $VERSION
IFS='.' read -a array <<< "$VERSION"
echo ${#array[@]}
echo ${array[@]}
```

But getting following error when I run `sh test.sh`

```
1.2.3
test.sh: 4: test.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

**Version** :

```
ubuntu@jenkins-slave1:~$ $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later         
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

**OS** :

```
ubuntu@jenkins-slave1:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: Also FWIW `$SHELL` is your user shell not necessarily `/bin/sh`, on ubuntu your `/bin/sh` is most likely `dash`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<<<` is a zsh operator now supported by a few other shells (including `bash`).

`read -a` is bash-specific. ksh had `read -A` for that long before bash (consistent with `set -A`; `set -a` being something else inherited from the Bourne shell; also supported by `zsh` and `yash`)

`sh` these days is an implementation or another of an interpreter for the POSIX `sh` language. That language has neither `<<<` nor `read -a` nor arrays (other than `"$@"`).

On Ubuntu, by default, the shell used as `sh` interpreter is `dash` which is very close to the POSIX `sh` specification in that it implements very few extensions over what POSIX specifies. It implements none of `<<<`, `read -a` nor arrays.

In POSIX `sh`, to split a string into the one POSIX `sh` array  (`"$@"`), you'd use:

```
IFS=.             # split on .
set -o noglob     # disable glob
set -- $VERSION"" # split+glob with glob disabled.
echo "$# elements:"
printf ' - "%s"\n' "$@"
```

It has a few advantages over the bash-specific `IFS=. read -a <<< $string` syntax:

- it doesn't need creating a temporary file and storing the contents of `$string` in it.
- it works even if `$string` contains newline characters (`read -a <<< $string`) would  only read the first line.
- it works even if `$string` contains backslash characters (with `read`, you need the `-r` option for backslash not to undergo a special processing).
- it's standard.
- it works for values like `1.2.`. `read -a <<< $string` would split it into `"1"` and `"2"` only instead of `"1"`, `"2"` and `""`.
- in older versions of `bash`, you had to quote the `$string` (`IFS=. read -ra <<< "$string"`) or otherwise it would undergo splitting (followed by joining with space).

Comment: Is it possible to create an array variable ?

Comment: @roy, as I said, `sh` has no array variables (other than `"$@"` which is not really a *variable*). shells with array variable support include `(t)csh`, `ksh`, `rc`, `bash`, `zsh`, `es`, `akanga`, `fish`, `yash`. Pick one. In that list, I'd recommend `zsh` or `rc`.

Answer (score 4):

You're hashbang is `/bin/sh` and you are running the script with `sh`, which does not support the `<<<` herestring.  If you use `/bin/bash` it will work.

Additionally, while `/bin/sh` often supports arrays it is not required to do so, if an array is required you should use `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`, or another shell that has support for them.